# Trying to return the total number of days in a year without datetime module

Tags: python

I am trying to get a return value of either 366 or 365 days depending on the year input. However, I get 'None' in return every single time.

Is there something I am missing?

```
year = int(input("Enter the year to determine the number of days: "))

def if_leap_year(year):

    if (year % 400 == 0) == True: return 366
    
    elif (year % 100 == 0) == True: return 365
    
    elif (year % 4 == 0) == True: return 366
    

print(if_leap_year(year))
```

Comment: you need to add a final `else: return 365`

Comment: Because you don't have an `else` clause to return the default, 365.  By the way, it is NEVER necessary to use `== True` in an `if` statement,  Just delete those.

Comment: What if the year specified doesn't match any of those cases?  Also, `if (year % 400 == 0) == True` can just be replaced with `if (year % 400 == 0):`

Comment: @ZLi thank you, I totally forgot to add the last else clause.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for the feedback. The reason I added `True` was because I used it as a last resort to see if there were any changes to the output, which there weren't.

Comment: One final critique: Python `if` statements don't need that extra set of parens.  That's a leftover habit from C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
year = int(input("Enter the year to determine the number of days: "))

def if_leap_year(year):

    if (year % 400 == 0): return 366

    elif (year % 100 == 0): return 365

    elif (year % 4 == 0): return 366
    
    else:
        return 365


print(if_leap_year(year))
```

add the final (added in above code already):

```
else:
     return 365
```